# as3 current frame check

Tags: actionscript-3, action, frame, collision

I have brick that is hit by  ball 2 times on the first hit it goes to frame 2, on the second hit goes to frame 3 and animation plays up to frame 40. Then the current frame property is supposed to execute _root.brickAmt --on frame 40, but it does not work. Can you tell me why? and how can I fix this?  Thanks!

```
if (this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)){ 
   if (this.currentFrame == 1){   
   this.gotoAndStop(2)
   } else if (this.currentFrame == 2) {                     
              this.gotoAndPlay(3)
        } 
        if (this.currentFrame == 40) {                     

removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
              _root.brickAmt --;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, writting code on the timeline is not usually a good practice, nevertheless here are a few things to notice:

1- Unless you put your code in every keyframe, it will execute exactly once.
1.1- If you want it to execute every frame without making dozens of keyframes and copypasting it everywhere you should put it inside a function and let this function be called on some listener, ideally on event.enter_frame

2- The if checking if frame is 40, is inside the if checking the hittest, are you sure on frame 40, the ball and the brick are touching?

3- I'm also not sure you are using AS2 or AS3, in AS3 _root should be replaced by MovieClip(root)

EDIT:
I couldn't open the .fla because I'm using an older version but accordin to what you said in the comments I'm pretty sure the code should be like this:

```
private function enterFrameEvents(event:Event):void{
  // [...] previous code
  if (this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)){ 
    if (this.currentFrame == 1){   
      this.gotoAndStop(2)
    } else if (this.currentFrame == 2) {                     
      this.gotoAndPlay(3)
    }
  } // <- Notice this
  if (this.currentFrame == 40) {                     
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
    _root.brickAmt --;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's As3.... The difficult part is that there should not be collision on frame 40, it should just execute brick Amt-- when it reaches that frame. If you remove  } 
        if (this.currentFrame == 40) it works bot without going to frame 40 and therefore without the Animation. Can you please take a look at it? https://app.box.com/s/whbrlx5lrr7avmsx3a9k

Comment: Thank you so much!. That was it.... just one bracket... I am sorry i did not see the update on your answer right away.... (Already have warning for a ban from this site for asking stupid questions like this one). You are Great! Thanks!

Comment: No ofense but is not that weird seeing how your code was formatted (on the source code you provided).
Just a tip, adobe flash has a button just over the place you write code, that can auto format the code so it doesn't look weird, and hopefully you can avoid stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is not inside a function that runs every frame, and there's more than 40 frame, you may miss it passing frame 40.
If not, check the timeline of *this* and make sure nothing else is interrupting it's progress before it reaches frame 40.

You can also put a trace statement into ENTER_FRAME function to see if it stops anywhere between.

```
// in a function inside the object that runs every frame
trace(this.currentFrame);
```

Comment: Thanks! If I have up to if (this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)){ 
   if (this.currentFrame == 1){   
   this.gotoAndStop(2)
   } else if (this.currentFrame == 2) {                     
              this.gotoAndPlay(3)  }   It works. can I say This. gotoandPlay 3 to 40 and then execute brickAmt--. How would I phrase it in code?

Comment: I tried trace(this.currentFrame); It would not work I think because it's called from a class in the 15 frame of a larger project.

Comment: There could be a million causes for that, depending on how your nested objects are structure, where is the code on the timeline and which part on each timeline is the program flow at the given time.

Comment: It is a really bad approach to try to develop stuff in this way. I suggest you to begin learning about how to develop an application with writing minimal or no code on keyframes. I'd only suggest you to stop whatever is you doing and watch this Official ActionScript tutorials about OOP, and how to write the program with collecting the code in files. Neat and tidy. [AdobeActionScript's channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/AdobeActionScript/videos) I suggest you to watch series 45 onward. Which about OOP.

Comment: Thank you! I watched some of these these episodes, but none of them answer my question. And actually This is a question that I have had for a long time. In every game we see animation playing before going to another level or some other action, and I have Never seen this explained anywhere. My app is written with minimal code, but it's unfortunate I can't continue working on it, because of this problem., which stands like a Mountain at this point.